# Prove that if $f(x)$ measurable on measurable set $E$ then $f^4(x)+7x^2$ measurable on $E$

Tags: measure-theory

> Prove that if $f(x)$ measurable on measurable set $E$ then $f^4(x)+7x^2$ measurable on $E$

*Attempt:*

for measurable functions $g(x),z(x)$the product $g(x)\cdot z(x)$ also measurable therfore $f^4(x)=\left(f(x)f(x)\right)\left(f(x)f(x)\right)$ measurable.

how can I prove that $7x^2$ is measurable?

Comment: That $7x^2$ is measurable follows because continuous functions are measurable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the fact that the sum of two measurable functions, the product of two measurable functions, the scalar multiple of any measureable function, and any continuous function, are measureable (on $\mathbb{R}$ with its usual Borel (topology-derived) structure).

- If $f$ is measurable, then so is $f^{4}(x) = f(x)\cdot f(x) \cdot f(x) \cdot f(x) $.
- The identity function $I(x)=x$ is measureable because it is continuous, which you can easily prove.
- Therefore, so is the function $g(x)=7x^2 = 7 \cdot I(x)\cdot I(x)$.
- Therefore, so is the function $(f+g)(x) = f^{4}(x) + 7x^2$.